# ffmpeg keeps converting second ac3 audio stream to mp2

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm new to this forum, and hope someone can help.
I am trying to add a second audio track (chinese.ac3) to an XVID video (vts_01.avi) that already has an ac3 track.

These audio tracks are encoded to ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s, and I would like to keep them that way -- just multiplex the streams without transcoding.

This is the command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -i vts_01.avi -vcodec copy -i Chinese.ac3 -acodec copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 muxed2.avi -newaudio
```

**ffmpeg does its work**, except for the fact that **it converts the second track to mp2, 64 kb/s.**

Here is a relevant excerpt from the output, where the key part is 'Stream #0.2: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s' where I would like 'Stream #0.2: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s':

```
Input #0, avi, from 'vts_01.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.5.0
  Duration: 02:03:26.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1954 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 720x352 [PAR 1:1 DAR 45:22], 23.98 tbr,
23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
[ac3 @ 018A7440] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5024000
[ac3 @ 018A7440] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, ac3, from 'Chinese.ac3':
  Duration: 02:03:26.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #1.0: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
File 'muxed2.avi' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, avi, to 'muxed2.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf53.5.0
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 720x352 [PAR 1:1 DAR 45:22], q=2-31, 23.
98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0.2: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
  Stream #1.0 -> #0.2
```

I have tried a number of different combinations, including explicitly forcing the stream to ac3 with:

```
ffmpeg -i vts_01.avi -vcodec copy -i chinese.ac3 -acodec ac3 -ac 2 -ar 48000 -ab 128k -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 muxed2.avi -newaudio
```

Same result.

I have also tried to assign a codec to the stream with stream specifier(based on http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Stream-specifiers-1, but these options are not recognized by my ffmpeg.

I am running out of things to try.

Answer (score 0):

(The OP edited the answer into the question. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I think I just found the solution
>
> from http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Encoding-with-multiple-Audio-tracks-td1289403.html There, James Darley says:

```
So your command line should look like:  
ffmpeg -i INPUT [output options] OUTPUT [audio options] -newaudio [subtitle options] -newsubtitle
```

> I then re-arranged my options accordingly, i.e. audio options for the new track after the output:

```
ffmpeg -i vts_01.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -i Chinese.ac3 muxed3.avi -acodec copy -newaudio
```

> And I now gets my two ac3 audio tracks at the right bitrate.